# query from Index in different Elasticsearch host

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I use RestHighLevelClient to execute a query.I generate my client with multiple nodes like this.

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
    RestClient.builder(
            new HttpHost("host1", 9200, "http"),
            new HttpHost("host2", 9200, "http"),
            new HttpHost("host2", 9200, "http")
    )
```

);

And do some query from several indices，But some of my index only exists in one nodes.It will cause index not found exception if i use client.search(xxx). How can i deal with this problem.

using IndicesOptions.LENIENT_EXPAND_OPEN won't throw index not found, but it seems that it just query from host1

Comment: can you host your code on GitHub, so that we can have a look, normally it should create a cluster and, the request goes to any node(in absence of dedicated coordinating node) and every node has cluster state, which knows which node has the data and query accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you form a ES cluster with all the 3 nodes. (Recommended)
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/add-elasticsearch-nodes.html

```
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
        new HttpHost("host1", 9200, "http"),
        new HttpHost("host2", 9200, "http"),
        new HttpHost("host3", 9200, "http")).build();
```

However if you want to stick with specific host for search then you should use create separate RestHighLevelClient for each node. (Not recommended)

```
RestClient restClientHost1 = RestClient.builder(
        new HttpHost("host1", 9200, "http")).build();
RestClient restClientHost2 = RestClient.builder(
        new HttpHost("host2", 9200, "http")).build();
RestClient restClientHost3 = RestClient.builder(
        new HttpHost("host3", 9200, "http")).build();
```